# HOw write sql sentence to get data from web service

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, web-services

I am trying to get some data from a web service:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json;', 
        url: 'http://***.asmx/GetJSONString',
        data: "Select * from con",
        crossDomain:true,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) { 
            alert(response); 
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, error) {
            alert("Error");
        }            
    });
```

where/how i have to write sql? in data?

Comment: It's not secure way to do queries like that. You should send some variables to file and then do your sql

Answer (score 1):

Yes but you forgot to pass a `POST` param name

It can be object:

```
data: { sqlQuery: "Select * from con" }
```

Or string:

```
data: "sqlQuery=Select * from con"
```

Now in your server side you will get `POST` variable `sqlQuery` with your SQL string.

Read more about [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: thanks for your answer but it still not workingt the error says : Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: thaks! but still not working. I´m starting to thin that is web-service problem.

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass this paramater as json string .. 
you can do this as

```
d={ sqlQuery: "Select * from con" }
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json;', 
    url: 'your url',
    data: JSON.stringify(d),
    crossDomain:true,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) { 
        alert(response); 
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, error) {
        alert("Error");
    }            
});
```

Comment: thaks! but still not working. I´m starting to thin that is web-service problem.

Comment: what error are you getting ?? ..it will not work unless your service has string parameter sqlQuery

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://*** Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: check this .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin